# Date wise Audio

Tags: html, audio

I have query regarding to start particular Audio on particular Date.

I have made a Button
and When I click a Button it start a Audio with last defined Day/Date.

Suppose I click button on 21-04-2020 so Audio 1 Should be Started
and if i Click a same button on 25-04-2020 so Audio 2 Should be started
and If I click a same button on 30-04-2020 so Audio 3 should be started.

Please advise and support with your coding ideas.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try the below in a browser or at https://jsfiddle.net/f3gLud0j/. I've added an extra line so it plays something today too.

```
<!doctype html>
<body>
    <audio id="audio1" src="https://www.bing.com/th?id=ODT.568AACA7B196763CD786C8A8C0122A28&pid=Dictionary" crossorigin="anonymous"></audio>
    <audio id="audio2" src="https://www.bing.com/th?id=ODT.209BD0B2797DB160F28AC1F865E5541A&pid=Dictionary" crossorigin="anonymous"></audio>
    <audio id="audio3" src="https://www.bing.com/th?id=ODT.057218D423FC3A3DDEA88E2979608FBA&pid=Dictionary" crossorigin="anonymous"></audio>
    <button id="btn">Click to play</button>
    <script>
        const btn = document.getElementById( "btn" )
        btn.addEventListener( "click", buttonClick )
        function buttonClick() {
            const audioId = `audio${ getAudioNumber() }`
            const audioElement = document.getElementById( audioId )
            audioElement.play()
        }
        function getAudioNumber() {
            const niceDate = getNiceDateString()
            switch ( niceDate ) {
                case "21-4-2020": return 1
                case "25-4-2020": return 2
                case "30-4-2020": return 3
                case "20-4-2020": return 3 // Remove if don't want sound today
                default: alert( `Sorry, no audio today (date ${ niceDate })` )
            }
        }
        function getNiceDateString() {
            const date = new Date()
            return `${ date.getDate() }-${ date.getMonth() + 1 }-${ date.getFullYear() }`
        }
    </script>
</body>
```